# El extraño caso de la palabra "video"

Tags: diferencias-regionales, acentuación

Esta palabra me ha llamado la atención debido a que, dependiendo del lugar donde la oiga su pronunciación es diferente.

En gran parte de las américas la escucho con la silaba tónica en la *e*, pero en otros lugares la he escuchado con la sílaba tónica en la *i*.

- vidéo - separar el diptongo deo en dos sílabas *de-o* terminando la palabra con 3 sílabas
- vídeo - con sílaba tónica en la *i*, terminando la palabra con dos sílabas.

¿Será que la palabra, al ser grave, no puede llevar tilde en ninguno de los dos casos, lo que produce ambas pronunciaciones?

Incluso he visto que los Ibéricos han decidido acentuar la "i"... lo que solo sería posible si "video" fuera una palabra esdrújula produciendo un acento prosódico sobre la *e*.... generando nuevamente vi-de-o.

¿Será que *video* es una palabra con dos acentos?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Según las normas de ortografía, hemos de considerar (a propósito de escritura) la secuencia de sonidos /bideo/ como una secuencia trisilábica. Eso se debe a que la *i* se encuentra entre consonantes, por lo que forma una sílaba, y a que las otras dos vocales son ambas abiertas (o fuertes) por lo que siempre se consideran como existiendo en sílaba propia.

Entonces, podemos decir que la palabra se separa así:

> VI — DE — O

Ahora, entran las reglas de acentuación.  Si la palabra se acentúa en la primera sílaba (técnicamente se cuenta desde atrás y es la antepenúltima), es esdrújula.  Si se acentúa la segunda (o penúltima), es llana.  Y si recae en la tercera (o última), es aguda.

Una palabra esdrújula siempre lleva tilde.  Así que, si la pronunciación es /'bi.de.o/, se escribe **vídeo** con tilde.

Una palabra llana lleva tilde si termina en consonante (excluyendo N y S) o si es necesario para evitar un diptongo en la escritura que es hiato en el habla.  En este caso, no hay diptongo en la escritura, y acaba en vocal.  Si la pronunciación es /bi'de.o/, se escribe **video** sin tilde.

Una palabra aguda lleva tilde si termina en vocal, N o S.  Como termina en vocal, si la pronunciación es /bi.de'o/, se escribe **videó** con tilde.

Lo que pasa es que según zona, hay dos pronunciaciones asentadas en la lengua.  Una es /'bi.de.o/ y la otra es /bi'de.o/.  Es imposible consolidar estas dos pronunciaciones en una escritura dado el sistema de ortografía en castellano, por lo tanto, hay dos formas de escribir la palabra.  La recomendación es escribir la forma que usas.

Answer (score 3):

Sí, hay dos formas válidas:

> #### video o vídeo.
>
> ‘Cierto sistema de grabación y reproducción de imágenes’. Procedente del inglés *video*, se ha adaptado al español con dos acentuaciones, ambas válidas:
>
> - la forma esdrújula *vídeo* `[bídeo]`, que conserva la acentuación etimológica, es la única usada en España;
> - en América, en cambio, se usa mayoritariamente la forma llana *video* `[bidéo]`.
>
> Cuando esta voz se emplea como elemento prefijo en la formación de compuestos, es átona y, por tanto, debe escribirse sin tilde (→ [<sup><sub>TILDE</sub></sup><sup>2</sup>](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=Adwesaq4ND64VT09xQ), [4.1](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=Adwesaq4ND64VT09xQ#41)): *videoconferencia, videoclub, videojuego.*
>
> - http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?key=video

Nota que la palabra inglesa viene del latín *videō* `/ˈwi.de.oː/` (de donde viene "veo").

Answer (score 1):

[*Diccionario panhispánico de dudas:* **video o vídeo**](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=video).

> ‘Cierto sistema de grabación y reproducción de imágenes’. Procedente
>   del inglés video, se ha adaptado al español con dos acentuaciones,
>   ambas válidas: la forma esdrújula vídeo [bídeo], que conserva la
>   acentuación etimológica, es la única usada en España; en América, en
>   cambio, se usa mayoritariamente la forma llana video [bidéo]. Cuando
>   esta voz se emplea como elemento prefijo en la formación de
>   compuestos, es átona y, por tanto, debe escribirse sin tilde