# ¿Cuándo se usa "visionar" un video (vs. "mirar")?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, verbos, diferencias-regionales

En una [pregunta reciente](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/28527/9385), leí:

> Mientras **visionaba** un vídeo en inglés sobre restauración de cuadros etc.

Lo cual se oye bastante raro para mí.

Me gustaría saber en cuáles países o regiones se expresa así, en lugar de "Mientras **miraba** un video."  (No estoy preguntando acerca de la [diferencia entre *vídeo* y *video*](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/26827/9385).)

Comment: En el  ámbito televisivo o cinematográfico si que se usa *visionar*. Visionar es más que ver o mirar, se mira el video de forma más crítica, fijandose en detalles técnicos o narrativos. De hecho acabo de ver que el DLE recoge ese significado también: https://dle.rae.es/?id=bvEYC9C

Answer (score 3):

Según la RAE:

> De visión.
>
> 1. tr. Creer que son reales cosas inventadas.
> 2. tr. Examinar técnica o críticamente, en una sesión de trabajo, un producto cinematográfico, televisivo, etc.

Así pues, en su segunda acepción se ve que se refiere al hecho de observar como espectador un vídeo.

En cuanto a la primera, significa "ver visiones", y por ende creer que son reales. No debe confundirse con `visualizar`, ya que éste denota separación clara entre realidad e imaginación o ficción.

Comment: ¿Es más común usar *visionar* en el sentido 2 en ciertos países?  Jamás había oído esto en México.

Answer (score 2):

Ese verbo se trata de describir el proceso de imaginar algo.

Un ejemplo:

> Visionar un nuevo mundo

Pues, "visionaba un video" indicaría que alquien sueña con una idea para un video.  Mejor dicho, imaginar una invención.

Comment: Perdón, @dockeryZ, no había puesto suficiente contexto.

Comment: Si tienes sugerencias, ponlas.